# python with addition and multiplication not understanding the code

Tags: python, function, recursion, multiplication, addition

can someone please help me to understand step by step this function, I have tried for hours with no luck. thank you.

```
def mult(a,b):
    # Take care of the base case!!
    if b == 1:
        return a

    return mult(a,b-1) + a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recursive function which performs repeated addition (which is what multiplication is). Adding a print statement:

```
>>> def mult(a, b):
...     print(a, b)
...     if b == 1:
...             return a
...     return mult(a, b - 1) + a
...
>>> mult(3, 5)
3 5
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 1
15
```

The base-case is `b == 1`, and notice that your recursive call decreases the value of `b` by 1, and adds the output to `a`. Since `a` never changes, all you're doing is adding `a` to itself `b` times (again, which is the same thing as multiplication).

Here's a very mediocre diagram. It's hard to see at first, but you'll get it eventually.

```
mult(2, 4) = 2 + mult(2, 3)
           = 2 + (2 + mult(2, 2))
           = 2 + (2 + (2 + mult(2, 1)))
           = 2 + (2 + (2 + (2)))  # base case
           = 2 + (2 + (4))
           = 2 + (6)
           = 8
```

Comment: I am still so confused how does that work, what are we adding at the end to get the result 15? I have been trying for 4 hrs to understand it. Why did we set the base case return to a instead of 0 or one? why we are not adding 3 to each recursive call??

Comment: @LenaAl. in the recursive call `return mult(a, b - 1) + a`, the call to `mult(a, b - 1)` must be evaluated first, before the `+ a`. Try to write down on paper what it looks like to go through a call `mult(2, 3)`.

Comment: mult(2,3) => mult(2, 2) + 2 => mult(2,1) => return 2.

Comment: how does the recursive call know to add those number, there is no addition sign?

Comment: @LenaAl. see my edit. I tried to draw a diagram. `mult(2, 2)` returns the result of `mult(2, 1) + 2` which, since `b` is 1 in that case, will return `2 + 2`. This is added to the first `+ 2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation; I have been trying to study recursion for 3 days for the first time. It is above my head. It is my first programming class in my first semester at college :)

Comment: @LenaAl. if you're satisfied, you should mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion to multiply a by b.  Recursion is a fairly advanced concept, so you may want to read about it.  The main idea of recursion is that a function calls upon itself repeatedly to solve a problem.  In order to avoid an infinite loop, there is always a base case.

In you case b starts at its original value and is decremented by 1 every time the function calls itself. Each time, a is added to itself. When b finally reaches 1, recursion stops and a value is returned. By then, a will have been added to itself b time; i.e. a multiplied by b.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation; I have been trying to study recursion for 3 days for the first time. It is above my head. It is my first programming class in my first semester at college :)